# Deleting subject and verb in a clause

Tags: ellipsis

> *When not a teacher*, he lived a life of a monk.

This sentence is perfectly possible and is missing a subject, so I was just curious if I can say this also.

> Students were absentminded, thinking what to do *when (they) get home
>   early.*
>
> If (they are) not doing homework, they get lazy.

Is it OK to delete "they" (or "they are") in these sentences?

Comment: anyone please? I am so desperate now.

Comment: No, it's not OK as written.  Perhaps "The students were absentminded, thinking what to do after gett**ing** home early."

Comment: What about "when not a teacher, he lived a life of a monk" and "if  not doing homework, they get lazy"?

Comment: Using this sentence formation, you would probably say "When not a teacher, he lived *the* life of a monk."  I can make your second sentence work, but it would sound much better with a subject in the "if" clause.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your first example ("the students"), no, you cannot delete the subject.

In your second example, yes, you can delete the subject, but it is not common to do so.

Comment: By first, do you mean "students were absentminded, thinking what to do when (they) get home early"?.

Comment: Or do you mean this? when not a teacher, he lived a life of a monk.

Comment: Rather a spare answer, which the OP @uoeirja should not have accepted so quickly.

Comment: @uoeirja By first example I mean the students.

Answer (score 2):

It is common to omit the subject and the verb *to be*, and if the subject and verb are lacking, it will almost always be interpreted as the verb *to be*. As such, you should only ever omit the verb *to be* and both it and the subject must be omitted.

This renders your first example nonsensical as "get" has no subject, and removing "get" will make it be interpreted as the following:

> Students were absentminded, thinking what to do when (they are) home early.*

*Early* without *get* leaves this more open to interpretation, for example, it could just be early in the morning, and furthermore the sentence does not sound natural so I would revise it as such:

> Students were absentminded when thinking about what to do when home from school early.

The "home from school" clarifies this.

Your second sentences, since it uses *to be*, is fine, as long as you remove both *they* and *are*.

> If (they are) not doing homework, they get lazy.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically right, because students would be implied in the first one and they in the second one. The second one, however, changes the meaning. "If not doing homework" is a dependent clause, not independent. So, in some cases, yes, and some, no.

Answer (score 0):

### First Example

In the following example that you provided, ***your use of "they" is correct. You can't omit it***.

> Students were absentminded, thinking what to do when they get home early.

You can ***not*** say the following:

> Students were absentminded, thinking what to do when get home early.

This is because ***it is not implied*** who you are talking about in the second part of the sentence.

---

### Second Example

This sentence, as you would probably expect, is correct:

> If they are not doing homework, they get lazy.

However, ***it is also perfectly acceptable*** to say:

> If not doing homework, they get lazy.

This is because ***it is implied*** who you are talking about in the second part of the sentence.

---

### Note

You said that it was perfectly acceptable to say this:

> When not a teacher, he lived a life of a monk.

This is ***correct***.

However, in English it does read better if you say (formally):

> When ***he was*** not a teacher, he lived ***the*** life of a monk.

Or (informally):

> When ***he wasn't*** a teacher, he lived ***the*** life of a monk.

As an English speaker myself, my preferred choice would be the latter.

---

### Conclusion

It is okay to omit "they" from the first part of the sentence as long as you make sure that the reader knows who you are writing about (he, she, they, we and so on) after they have read the second part of the sentence.